# KeyDown not working

Tags: macos, cocoa, keydown

I'm trying to perform a certain action by pressing, for example the spacebar (anywhere). In my code, I've got the acceptsFirstResponder method and the keyDown method but I'm not getting an NSLog-message

Here the code:

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
return YES;
}
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
NSLog(@"test");
}
```

Comment: this code is in my appdelegate.m file

Comment: Of course it doesn't work, the code has to be in a subclass of NSResponder.

Comment: @TheAmateurProgrammer Ok, I just created a new class (subclass of NSResponder) with the two methods, but I don't get any nslog when I press a key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put your -keyDown: method on an NSView subclass, and that NSView subclass has to be put in a window, and that window has to be on-screen, and you have to click on your view before you hit a key. Then the key will go to your view.

Check the diagram “The Path of Key Events” [on this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/eventoverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html).

Comment: I'm using a storyboard with `NSViewController` subclass and `NSView` subclass. `mouseDown(with:)` gets called, but `keyDown(with:)` doesn't...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to implementing `keyDown` in your `NSView`, you also need to implement `acceptsFirstResponder` and have it return `YES`:

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```